# This hack to allow "pin to start" for files (not just folders) doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

[This article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/pin-file-to-start-menu-windows-10) proposes the following to add "pin to start" functionality for files (besides folders) in Windows 10:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Created by TheWindowsClub
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PinToStartScreen]
@="{470C0EBD-5D73-4d58-9CED-E91E22E23282}"
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work even though I get a confirmation message that the keys and values were successfully added to registry. Right click on files still doesn't include "pin to start".

Any idea?

Comment: I would imagine that it stopped working after one of the twice-a-year Feature Updates.  Of course, there is always the traditional workaround that will allow you to [Pin to Start](https://superuser.com/a/1192264/650163).

Comment: The article was written against Windows 10 1507.  A good amount of what was possible in that build was no longer possible even in 1511.  Did perform a reboot after you made the registry change?